# Mathematical approach to derive Modulo expression

Tags: java, modulo

Below are two expressions to find modulo(n,d) in java, using euclidean division

```
(d + (n % d))  if (n < 0)

(n%d)  if n > 0
```

My question is,

Am not clear, How to think mathematically before writing above expression, if n<0?

Please help me with mathematical approach, Because i do not want to remember logic!!!

Comment: I don't quite understand your dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remember what `n % d` does, it returns a value in the range `(-d, d)` congruent mod d to n and matching the sign of n.

If you want to know how to get a positive result (or strictly speaking, a result matching the sign of d instead of n), there's an easier way than the `if`.

Since `(n % d)` is in the range `(-d, d)`, that means `(n % d) + n` is in the range `(0, 2d)`, so `((n % d) + n) % d` is a value in the range `[0, d)`, congruent to n.

Thus, `((n % d) + n) % d` is what you're looking for.